# Change background image dynamically on checked checkbox

Tags: jquery, html

Hi this is my first question in the stackoverflow community and I am having problems changing the background image of my webpage dynamically when a checkbox is checked

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><label for="Lines">Add Fun: </label><input type="checkbox" id="Lines" name="Lines" /></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if ($('#Lines').is(':checked')) {
                    $("body").css({'background-image': 'url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Mud_wrestling_couple.jpg)'});
        }
</script>
```

I want it to change the background of the body as soon as the checkbox is checked. The image is just a random one I found online. Think I might be overlooking something. Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://i.chzbgr.com/maxW500/6928617728/hA937289F/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this

```
​$(function(){
    $('#Lines').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) 
        {
            $("body").css({ 'background-image': 'url(image url)' });
        }
        else $("body").css({'background-image':''});
    });
});​
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xhwFd/).

Comment: 16,500 rep! Wow! :) That's a lot... I have 200. :) But you deserve it all. ;) You get rep by being helpful...

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to do the check once the checkbox is altered.. so use the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change) event handler

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Lines').change(function(){
       if (this.checked){
          $("body").css({'background-image': 'url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Mud_wrestling_couple.jpg)'});
       } else {
          // here you should do what you want when the user un-checks the checkbox..
       }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Lines').click(function ()
{
 if ($(this).is(':checked'))
 {
   $("body").css({'background-image': 'url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Mud_wrestling_couple.jpg)'});
 }
});
```